# Find only two numbers in array that evenly divide each other

Tags: algorithm

Find the only two numbers in an array where one evenly divides the other - that is, where the result of the division operation is a whole number

```
Input Arrays  Output
5 9 2 8       8/2 = 4
9 4 7 3       9/3 = 3
3 8 6 5       6/3 = 2
```

The brute force approach of having nested loops has time complexity of `O(n^2)`. Is there any better way with less time complexity?

This question is part of [advent of code](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/2).

Comment: Think of the worst case scenario (no such pair exists).

Comment: What is the upper range for the numbers inside the array?

Comment: The linked question doesn't involve divisors -- it says to subtract the smallest from the largest.

Comment: The the linked question need to be solved, to reveal the divisors part :-). Will post more details here soon. Also there is a garuntee that one pair exists. There is no upper range, so think of max value of an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Given an array of numbers A, you can identify the denominator by multiplying all the numbers together to give E, then testing each i<sup>th</sup> element by dividing E by A<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>. If this is a whole number, you have found the denominator, as no other factors can be introduced by multiplication.

Once you have the denominator, it's a simple task to do a second, independent loop searching for the paired numerator.

This eliminates the n<sup>2</sup> comparisons.

**Why does this work?** First, we have an n-2 collection of non-divisors: abcde..
To complete the array, we also have numerator x and denominator y.

However, we know that x and only x has a factor of y, so it can be expressed as yz (z being a whole remainder from the division of x by y)

When we multiply out all the numbers, we end up with xyabcde.., but as x = yz, we can also say y<sup>2</sup>zabcde..

When we loop through dividing by the squared i'th element from the array, for most of the elements we create a fraction, e.g. for a:

y<sup>2</sup>zabcde.. / a<sup>2</sup> = y<sup>2</sup>zbcde.. / a

However, for y and y only:

y<sup>2</sup>zabcde.. / y^2 = zabcde..

**Why doesn't this work?** The same is true of the other numbers. There's no guarantee that a and b can't produce another common factor when multiplied. Take the example of [9, 8, 6, 4], 9 and 8 multiplied equals 72, but as they both include prime factors 2 and 3, 72 has a factor of 6, also in the array. When we multiply it all out to 1728, those combine with the original 6 so that it can divide soundly by 36.

**How might this be fixed?** More accurately, if y is a factor of x, then y's prime factors will uniquely be a subset of x's prime factors, so maybe things can be refined along those lines. Obtaining a prime factorization should not scale according to the size of the array, but comparing subsets would, so it's not clear to me if this is at all useful.

Comment: Is *n* the number of values? Then how does that work on input array [2, 3, 8] and *n² = 9*?

Comment: Your method might generate false positive denominators, e.g., for [9, 4, 6] it will tell you that 6 is a denominator although it is not.

Comment: You might be correct for /any/ array, but the question specifies there will be one and only one whole division by the numerator/divisor pair. For your array, none exists.

Comment: @trincot dividing by the n'th number in the array, squared. So you'd multiply 2 x 3 x 8 = 48, then divide by 4, 9, and 64 to find that 48/4 = 12, and that 2 is your numerator.

Comment: @Danikov don't get me wrong I like the idea, it's just that you may get false positives. Lest's say we take [9, 4, 6, 2] then you will get 6 and 2 as denominator candidates and have to check for both. There may be scenarios where you will get a lot more ruining you O(n) runtime.

Comment: @SaiBot you're absolutely right. Do I delete a bad answer, or leave it for people to see what not to do?

Comment: @Danikov I actually think the idea is valuable. Maybe it is possible to work something out of it or possibly someone is able show that it is still faster than O(n^2). I would leave it. In case it gets negative votes you can get reputation back if you delete it.

Comment: OK, @Danikov, I see you improved the text by mentioning the divisor (An)² which is indeed clearer than n. But it would be better to use another letter than *n*, which is used in the time complexity as the size of the input. Better (Ai)², for i in 1..n.

Comment: @SaiBot I've realised that [9, 4, 6, 2] is actually invalid as 4/2 and 6/2 means that two pairs divide evenly. Can you think of another counter-example?

Comment: @Danikov yes I realized that too, I just wanted a quick example to show the problem without thinking about the validity. I think [9, 8, 6, 4] should work. (8,4) is the desired output. But 9*8*6*4 is divisible by 8^2, 4^2 and by 6^2. It would be interesting if you could somehow show that the maximum number of candidates is bounded.

Comment: Very nice.  Overflow might be an issue for the general case, so but I suspect that shouldn't be an issue for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `O(n^2)` is the best time complexity you can get without any assumptions on the data.

If you can't tell anything about the numbers, knowing that `x` and `y` do not divide each other tells you nothing about `x` and `z` or `y` and `z` for any `x, y, z`. Therefore, in the worst case you must check all pairs of numbers - equal to `n Choose 2 = n*(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)`.

Comment: Instinctively I think `O(n^2)` is the lower bound too, so +1, but the tricky part is to come up with a more formal proof.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, we can get `O(n * sqrt(m))`, where `m` is the absolute value range, by listing the pairs of divisors of each element against a hash of unique values in the array. This can be more efficient than `O(n^2)` depending on the input.

```
5 9 2 8

list divisor pairs (at most sqrt m iterations per element m)
5 (1,5)
9 (1,9), (3,3)
2 (1,2)
8 (1,8), (2,4) BINGO!
```

Comment: what do you mean `by listing the pairs of divisors of each element against a hash of unique values in the array`

Comment: @mc20 I mean checking each pair of divisors to see if one of them is a value in the array. In the example I gave, 2 is a divisor of 8, and since we can test in `O(1)` if 2 exists in the array, we find our solution.

Comment: @SaiBot not sure I understand. Isn't the task to find the only pair in the array where one number is a divisor of the other? All I'm suggesting is to list the divisors and see if one of those divisors is an element in the array.

Comment: Nvm i misunderstood your description. I have to think about it. BTW I did not downvote.

Comment: @גלעדברקן to get `O(1)` , are you suggesting to use a hash set with space compelxity at `O(n)` ?

Comment: Factorizing the numbers has the potential to be far more expensive, though, and you still have to test all the factors against the original array.

Comment: @Danikov thank you for your comment. I did not suggest factorising (meaning primes only) but rather listing each element's divisor pairs. This is a loop that takes `O(1)` space and at most `sqrt(m)` iterations per element, whers `m` is the element. For each divisor pair, we check if one of them exists as an element in the array (since that is essentially the task). The latter check can be done in `O(1)` after an `O(n)` construction of a hash table, where each element is the key. As we both suggested, this would only be more efficient in some, not all input cases.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, how is listing each element's divisor pairs not factorisation?

Comment: @Danikov I think of factorisation as prime-factorisation. No worries, no need to argue about semantics. Do you get the gist of the idea?

Comment: I think I do. You loop through 1..sqrt(m) testing for all divisors in pairs, then look to see if any of the divisors are in the array (via. an O(1) collection of the array values, rather than searching the array)

Answer (score 0):

If you prime factorise all the numbers in the array progressively into a tree, when we discover a completely factored number leaf while factoring another number, we know we've found the divisor.

However, given we don't know which number is the divisor, we do need to test all primes up to divisor's largest factor. The largest factor for any m-digit number is, at most, sqrt(m), while the average number of primes below any m-digit number is m / ln(m). This means we will make at most n (sqrt(m) / ln(sqrt(m)) operations with very basic factorization and no optimization.

To be a little more specific, the algorithm should keep track of four things: a common tree of explored prime factors, the original number from the array, its current partial factorization, and its position in the tree.

For each prime number, we should test all numbers in the array (repeatedly to account for repeated factors). If the number divides evenly, we a) update the partial factorization, b) add/navigate to the corresponding child to the tree, c) if the partial factorization is 1, we have found the last factor and can indicate a leaf by adding the terminating '1' child, and d) if not, we can check for other numbers having left a child '1' to indicate they are completely factored.

When we find a child '1', we can identify the other number by multiplying out the partial factorization (e.g. all the parents up the tree) and exit.

For further optimization, we can cache the factorization (both partial and full) of numbers. We can also stop checking further factors of numbers that have a unique factor, narrowing the field of candidates over time.

Comment: Posted separately as it's significantly different from my other answer.

Comment: Problematic if `m` is large.  Also `n (sqrt(m) / ln(sqrt(m))` assumes that you already have a list of primes up to `sqrt(m)`, which (practically) takes an additional `O(sqrt(m) ln ln sqrt(m))`.  Depending on the relative size of `n` vs `sqrt(m)` this term may dominate.